# Veux-tu des « pétacles » avec tes « peutates » pilées ?

Tags: prononciation, orthographe, québec, origine-ou-raison, régionalismes

> Veux-tu des patates (pommes de terre) ?
>  Veux-tu des
>   *pétacles/petaques/pataques* ? 
>  Veux-tu des *peutates* (pilées) ?

Le mot [*pétacle*](https://www.wikebec.org/petacles/definition/) semble être un [québécisme](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois) et on nous dit qu'avec *pilées*, c'est *peutates* et non *pétacles* (Wikébec). On le trouve au [GPFC](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois) sous les graphies *pataque* et *petaque* sans accent.  On nous dit que l'on trouvait *patache, patade* dans les dialectes de Poitou, Anjou, Bas-Maine, ou Bretagne (GPFC).

1. Laquelle des graphies de la déformation de *patate* est-elle la plus
   employée (au Québec) ; connaît-on une de ces prononciations ou « graphies » à l'extérieur du Québec ?
2. Comment diffèrent *peutate* et *pétacle* dans l'usage (hormis avec *pilé*) ; qu'est-ce qui motiverait le choix de l'un ou de l'autre ?
3. Est-il courant de trouver deux déformations différentes d'un même mot (*pétacles etc./peutates*) dont l'une ferait exclusivement partie d'un mot composé (*peutates pilées*) ; la *déformation* est-elle un phénomène, une caractéristique ou un procédé stylistique ; généralement à quoi « servent » ces déformations ?

Comment: Un réponse très partielle donc juste un commentaire "connaît-on une de ces prononciations ou « graphies » à l'extérieur du Québec ?". En Belgique, je n'ai jamais entendu ni l'une ni l'autre des autres formes de "patate". De plus le terme pilée n'est à ma connaissance jamais utilisé dans ce contexte car on parle généralement de "purée (de pommes de terre)" et quand on ne précise pas de quoi, c'est d'office de patates...

Comment: @LaurentS. Merci pour l'info. Oui, bien moi aussi je dirais _purée_ si j'avais à l'écrire, est-ce que j'aurais dit _purée de_ ou _en purée_, ça varie selon ce qui l'est je pense. En outre l’hummus fait de pois chiches c'est une purée de, pas des pois chiches pilés. Mais à table chez nous je t'offrirais des patates pilées, peut-être avec en plus des patates pas pilées ! D'ailleurs j'ai vu dernièrement Gordon en faire avec du paprika hahah.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) La variation de la première voyelle est *de loins* la plus commune au Québec (quoique "pétaque" ne soit pas inconnu). C'est généralement "pétate", moins souvent "peutate" où le "eu" ici transcrit non pas le son qu'on a dans dans *eux*, mais plutôt un [schwa](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa), son qui en français  est généralement légèrement arrondi. On peut entendre un son similaire (il n'est pas facile de dire si c'est un schwa, un /œ/ ou un é) dans [ce clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMeYds12ycM), très célèbre au Québec.

2) ... par la prononciation? Je ne vois pas comment la réponse pourrait être plus évidente (ou la question moins claire...).

3) C'est extrêmement fréquent puisque différentes forces élocutoires tentent d'appliquer des changement différents à la prononciation, et différents dialectes appliquent généralement des forces différentes. En outre (comme c'est le cas de *é* vs *eu* ici), il y a très fréquemment une variation continue et non des formes bien définies.

Answer (score 2):

Je dirais que Wikébec est dans les patates avec son Nota Bene ;) Il n'y a d'ailleurs aucune source pour justifier leur exemple. Peutate comme le son 'eux' est rarissime, et tout comme pétacle/pétaque/pataque qui est très commun, serait surtout utilisé de façon humoristique informelle. Quelqu'un qui utilise une de ces prononciation sans aucun pointe d'ironie (ce qui n'est pas évident à détecter pour quelqu'un n'ayant pas grandi au Québec) possède un bas niveau d'éducation.

Pour répondre point par point

1) Patate, de très loin.

2) Ce serait un choix stylistique prenant en compte la voix et le caractère du personnage qu'on souhaite recréer, le rythme de la phrase, les rhymes.

3) Il n'y a aucune préférence pour l'usage d'une prononciation d'un mot suivi de 'pilé' ou autre qualificatif comme 'au four'. Ces 'déformations' n'en sont pas toujours : elles sont parfois simplement un accent régional ou familial. Quand la pronociation est exagérée par choix, c'est le plus souvent dans le but de faire rire.

Answer (score 1):

Je suis d'accords avec Circeus pour le mot patates, mais j'ajoute de l'information sur le mot *pétacles*

Cette expression est pour moi beaucoup moins utilisé dans la région du Québec ou que je vit. Je l'ai entendue pour la première fois dans mon début vingtaine. Certain texte semble relier cette prononciation au Sud du Québec. Ma belle grand-mère utilisait ce mot, et elle était originaire de la Gaspésie. Ma belle famille me disais que le mot était d'expression acadienne comme origine.

Ici un texte qui semble donner un origine au mot; Ici il semble dire que c'est d'origine galloromane;

> En Nouvelle-France,  l'évolution  du mot  s'est faite  différemment.
>   
> La patate douce connue en français de  référence  n'est  pas 
>   cultivable  ici  en  raison  des  conditions  climatiques  de 
>   la province de Québec.  La Conquête anglaise a introduit le peuple
>   québécois à la culture de la pomme de terre au Canada *(Juneau 206)*;
>   c'est  alors que le terme patate,  du français rural  et populaire,
>   est  aussitôt  devenu  le  terme  courant  sur  l'ensemble  du 
>   territoire  et  le  demeure encore  aujourd'hui  *(PPQ  Q. 781,  Lavoie 
>   Q.  1192)*. 
>    Le  nom patate  est  donc  attesté  ici depuis  1764 
>   dans  un journal :«[...]  ils  ne  payeront  pas  à  l'avenir  la 
>   dime  des  patates  au Clergé  [...]»  *(La  Gazette de  Québec, 29 
>   novembre  1764,  p.  1,  FTLFQ)*. 
>    Toutefois,  il devait  être  connu 
>   et  employé dès le Régime français, car  ses variantes  dialectales 
>   d'origine galloromane pataque, pétaque, pétate  et pactaque  sont  très
>   répandues  et  même  attestées dans  les  documents  écrits jusqu'à 
>   aujourd'hui  (Juneau  206,  DHFQ  401).
>    De  plus,  il  est possible
>   que le terme anglais potato  ait contribué à la suprématie du terme
>   patate  au Québec *(Maguire  71,  Colpron1  68,  Juneau  206,  DHFQ 
>   401)*.    Dans  le  même  ordre  d'idées,  la locution pomme  de terre
>   est  connue  du peuple québécois,  mais elle s'emploie  plus
>   rarement depuis  le début  du  19e siècle  (Juneau  206, PPQ  Q. 781,
>   Lavoie  Q.  1192, DHFQ 401). 
>   En terminant,  le mot patate  est  à 
>   l'origine  de  nombreuses  expressions  et  extensions  de  sens
>   au Québec et  en France  *(FEW 20 : 58, TLF  12 :  1155, Juneau 
>   206-218, GRLF 7 : 167, DHLF2 : 1445-1446, DHFQ 398-404*

[Ref](https://constellation.uqac.ca/475/1/24752109.pdf)